# Latex issue with python on mac

Tags: mac, python

I was trying to run

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
```

on python, but I received the following error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex':
>   'latex'

Then I tried

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["latex"])
```

and again, I got

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex':
>   'latex'

so I went ahead and tried

```
whereis latex
```

on terminal and got no response. So I thought I might not have LaTeX installed, but then I realized I do have LaTeXiT software installed on my mac which works perfectly fine, so I should have LaTeX on my mac. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to solve the issue.

---

EDITS:

I have been experiencing this problem once in a while and I feel that there is no comprehensive answer for it. I'm looking for an answer that can run

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["latex"])
```

for the starters.

Comment: You might have `pdflatex` installed instead.

Comment: I tried  `whereis pdflatex` but no outputs

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with the tool you mentioned, but it seems that under `Preferences > Typesetting > Behaviour` you might find where the binaries are located. Source:  http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html

Comment: There it is, it's `TeXlive`. Thanks!

Comment: The TeXLive bin will have `latex` as well as many other binaries.  You'll need to make sure that directory is in your path.

Comment: It works for me, see [here](https://pastebin.com/BZ2BpaiW) for log dump.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you remember how you have installed Latex? from http://www.tug.org/mactex/?

Comment: @Teepeemm How do I set the path?